# UI suddenly changes after adding UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm facing a weird problem when I'm trying to adding UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell that the UI collapsing suddenly and I don't know why.

I have tried to make it dynamic height but didn't work.

And the CollectionView isn't scrolling also, I don't know why? When I'm hiding TableViewCell the scroll of CollectionView works perfectly.

**Before scrolling TableView:**

[image]

**After scrolling TableView:**

[image]

**CollectionViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init(coder adecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(codeer:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var categoriesImage: UIImageView = {
        let categoriesImage = UIImageView()
        categoriesImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        categoriesImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        categoriesImage.image = UIImage(named: "pizza")
        categoriesImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        categoriesImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        categoriesImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesImage
    }()

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .black
        containerView.alpha = 0.7
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoryName: UILabel = {
        let categoryName = UILabel()
        categoryName.textColor = .white
        categoryName.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        categoryName.text = "Soup"
        categoryName.textAlignment = .left
        categoryName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoryName
    }()

    lazy var recipesNumber: UILabel = {
        let recipesNumber = UILabel()
        recipesNumber.textColor = .white
        recipesNumber.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 16)
        recipesNumber.text = "33"
        recipesNumber.textAlignment = .left
        recipesNumber.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return recipesNumber
    }()

    func setupcategoriesImageConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            categoriesImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            categoriesImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            categoriesImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.topAnchor),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.bottomAnchor),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.leadingAnchor),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesImage.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoryNameConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoryName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            categoryName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            categoryName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
        ])
    }

    func setuprecipesNumberConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            recipesNumber.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            recipesNumber.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            recipesNumber.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(categoriesImage)
        categoriesImage.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoryName)
        containerView.addSubview(recipesNumber)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupcategoriesImageConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoryNameConstraints()
        setuprecipesNumberConstraints()
    }
}
```

**CollectionViewInTableViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.heightAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoriesNameLabel.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}

extension CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.frame.width / 2, height: self.frame.width / 4)
    }

}
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .white
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        containerView.layer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 2, height: 2)
        containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 7.0
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
//        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var foodImage: UIImageView = {
        let foodImage = UIImageView()
        foodImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        foodImage.clipsToBounds = true
        foodImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        return foodImage
    }()

    lazy var foodTitle: UILabel = {
        let foodTitle = UILabel()
        foodTitle.textColor = .CustomGreen()
        foodTitle.numberOfLines = 0
        foodTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return foodTitle
    }()

    func setupContainerView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodImage() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            foodImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            foodImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            foodImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
        ])
    }

    func setupFoodTitle() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: foodImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            foodTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            foodTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            foodTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(foodImage)
        containerView.addSubview(foodTitle)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubview()
        setupContainerView()
        setupFoodImage()
        setupFoodTitle()
    }

}
```

**HomeView:**

```
class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = .white
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
//        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .customDarkGray(), indicatorColor: .white)
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("https://api.url").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: response.data!)
                self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView()
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return recipesDetails.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.frame = CGRect.zero
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
        cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title
        cell.frame = CGRect.zero
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return 160

        } else {
            return 250
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I couldn't read all of these codes because of my workload but I think you should change the hugging and resistance priorities of constraints. Maybe `collectionView`'s hugging priority is bigger than `tableView`'s.

Comment: @Ahmed Abd Elaziz Seems you're put like `cell.frame = CGRect.zero` for UITableView and UICollectionView cells at `cellForRowAt`. That's the reason your cell frame where changing during scroll.

Comment: @emrcftci I think so, but I don't know actually how to do it because It's my first time to make UI programmatically.

Comment: @Ram What should I delete from them or edit?

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz comment this and run `cell.frame = CGRect.zero`

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh Thanks, the layout is fixed but still, CollectionView doesn't scroll it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your by removing `cell.frame = CGRect.zero`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
    cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
    cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the layout is fixed but still, CollectionView doesn't scroll it's fixed not moving.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz how many count available in `numberOfItemsInSection` for `categories` ?

Comment: There are 12 items in categories array

Comment: what is the value of `categoriesNameLabel.heightAnchor` ? can you make it as constant ?

Comment: Okay can you see the hierarchy of the collection view ? check all the properties regarding scroll like scroll, Paging enabled, check the frame of collection view, Cell content View, Cell ui elements and add this code `collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true` and try